# Slick2d - LWJGL Applet not finding /LZMA/LzmaInputStream

Tags: java, applet, lwjgl, slick2d, lzma

I can't run a Slick2d/lwjgl applet on my website and the only error I can see is this:

`WARNING: No file found for: /LZMA/LzmaInputStream.class`

Here is my applet code:

```
<applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" codebase="." width="640" height="480">
    <param name="al_title" value="flyingmongoose">
    <param name="al_main" value="test.SetupClass">
    <param name="al_jars" value="FlyingMongoose.jar, lwjgl.jar, lzma.jar, slick.jar">
    <param name="al_windows" value="windows_natives.jar">
    <param name="al_linux" value="linux_natives.jar">
    <param name="al_mac" value="macosx_natives.jar">
    <param name="separate_jvm" value="true">
</applet>
```

I have all the `jar` files in the war folder. I have also added `lwjgl.jar`, `lzma.jar`, `slick.jar` to the build path to see if it would help, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar" codebase="." width="640" height="480">
```

needs to be

```
<applet code="org.lwjgl.util.applet.AppletLoader" archive="lwjgl_util_applet.jar, lzma.jar" codebase="." width="640" height="480">
```